# Difference Between Pipeline and PowerShell class in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I want to know the difference between executing PowerShell script in `C#` using the `Pipeline` class versus the `PowerShell` class.

Using Pipeline :

```
Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
```

Using PowerShell class:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
```

We can use both of them to execute PowerShell script in C#, but what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation.  A `pipeline` is a feature of a `runspace`.  The `PowerShell.Create()` method will create a `PowerShell` object, a kind of wrapper for everything contained.  Both of these methods belong to the same PowerShell SDK.

The `Pipeline` is intended to run commands and is underneath the `runspace` object.

### More

[Pipeline Class (msdn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

[PowerShell Class (msdn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

Comment: @mklement0 I've updated my answer, but my understanding of the paradigm is the `PowerShell` type is a kind of wrapper and handles the `runspace`/`pipeline` setup/teardown while those other methods (using `runspacefactory` and `Runspace.CreatePipeline` are lower-level details you can manipulate.

Answer (score 6):

Note: The [PowerShell SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell) is very sparse, so the following is *speculative*.

- An instance of the [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) class is a wrapper for a *runspace*, the container in which a PowerShell session runs; its `.RunSpace` property returns the enclosed runspace.
- You need a runspace ([`RunSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) instance) in order to create and execute a *pipeline* for executing arbitrary PowerShell statements.
- To create a pipeline, you have two options:

  - If you have a `PowerShell` instance, you can use its convenience methods such as `.AddScript()` to *implicitly* create a pipeline.
  - Alternatively, use a runspace's [`.CreatePipeline()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.createpipeline?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Runspaces_Runspace_CreatePipeline_System_String_) method to create and manage a pipeline *explicitly*.

Simply put: **The convenience methods of the `PowerShell` class allow simpler creation and execution of pipelines.**

Note that *both* approaches support executing *multiple* statements, including any mix of commands (e.g., cmdlet invocations) and expressions (e.g.,`1 + 2`).

The following snippet compares the two approaches (using PowerShell itself), which are functionally equivalent, from what I can tell:

```
# Create a PowerShell instance and use .AddScript() to implicitly create
# a pipeline that executes arbitrary statements.
[powershell]::Create().AddScript('Get-Date -DisplayHint Date').Invoke()

# The more verbose equivalent using the PowerShell instance's .RunSpace
# property and the RunSpace.CreatePipeline() method.
[powershell]::Create().RunSpace.CreatePipeline('Get-Date -DisplayHint Date').Invoke()
```

There may be subtleties that I'm missing; do tell us, if so.